# Google Analytics 4: How do I track visitors from different Sub-Domains using one tag on my Main-Domain?

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, google-analytics-4

I am using GA4,tagged my main domain and now I can track and see how many visitors came through, from where are they etc...
This main-domaim, has more sub-domains that lead to it (DNS records, elliases) - and I want Google Analytics to show me, via the main-domain tag, from where each of the users came from.
How can it be done?
thanks.

I am using Fiddler Classic to see the traffic from my sub-domains to the main domain and I can see that the Miscellaneous header getting passed with the correct Referrer data: this the one I'm interest in monetizing, but in no way I can configure the board to show me this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to view data about which specific subdomain a user came from before visiting your main domain, you need to ensure you are capturing the full URL (with the subdomain) in GA4.

Here's how you can do it:

1. **Ensure Proper Setup of Your Property**:

   - Ensure that your GA4 property is set up to track all of your subdomains. This means that the tracking code from your GA4 property should be present on all subdomains and the main domain.
2. **Capture Full URL**:

   - In GA4, go to `Events` in the left sidebar.
   - Click on `Page view` event.
   - Check if `page_location` parameter is there. This parameter contains the full URL of the page, including the subdomain. If not, you might need to modify your tracking setup to capture this parameter.
3. **Create a Custom Report**:

   - In GA4's Analysis Hub, you can create a new report.
   - Add `Page view` as a metric.
   - Add `page_location` as a dimension to see the breakdown of page views by the full URL, which includes the subdomain.
4. **Referrer Data**:

   - If you're particularly interested in the referrer data that you're observing via Fiddler, you should look at the `referrer` parameter under the `Page view` event. This will tell you the full URL of the referring site.
5. **Custom Dimensions** (Advanced):

   - If you want to break down your reports by subdomain specifically, you can create a custom dimension for `Subdomain` and use that in your reports. You'd generally set this up through Google Tag Manager to extract the subdomain from the `page_location` and send it as a custom dimension with each hit.
6. **Ensure Cross-Domain Tracking**:

   - If you have separate main domains (not subdomains) leading to each other and you want to preserve the referral information across them, you'll need to set up cross-domain tracking. This ensures that visits across your domains are treated as a single session and the referral information is preserved.

Lastly, remember that with any changes to your tracking setup, you'll only capture new data moving forward. You won't see historical data for any new dimensions or metrics you set up.